# How to return stubbed Observable<void> in RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular9

I am trying to stub API and thus I would like to return stubbed response from my Service.

My service method looks like:

```
public addItem(item): Observable<void> {
    this.listOfItems.push(item);
    return of();
}
```

And my component method looks like:

```
public submit(): void {
   this.service.addItem(this.item)
       .subscribe(() => console.log('working'));
}
```

Unfortunately this way subscribe is not entered and nothing is displayed in console.

How can I return empty `Observable<void>` that could be subscribed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void` means nothing, try to use `undefined`.

```js
return of(undefined);
```

otherwise you can always use the ugliest `any` hack, but for tests it is acceptable, to avoid complexity during recreation of properly typed mocks and save some time with a fast `any` cast IMO.

```js
return <any>of(true);
```

Comment: nice, glad to hear!